# Is the sum of two isomorphic linear transformations also an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a possibly infinite vector space. Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ and $F:V \rightarrow V$ be two isomorphic linear transformations. Then, **is $T + F$ also an isomorphism?**

I believe the answer is *yes*. Since $T$ and $F$ are both automorphisms, there should be no reason as to why their sum would not be an isomorphism as well, right? My reasoning is as follows:

Let $v \in V$. Then $T + F$ has the mapping $T(v) + F(v)$, and this is a linear transformation, since $\forall$ real scalars $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\forall \thinspace \thinspace v,w \in V$:

$\begin{align}
(T+F)(\alpha v + \beta w) = & \enspace T(\alpha v + \beta w) +F(\alpha v + \beta w)
\\ = & \enspace \alpha T(v) + \beta T(w) + \alpha F(v) + \beta F(w)
\\ = & \enspace \alpha(T + F)(v) + \beta (T+F)(w)
\end{align}$

which itself is an isomorphism. Is this all correct?

Comment: And $T+(-T)$ is also an isomorphism? The sum is certainly a linear ransformation, but there's no reason why it should necessarily be bijective.

Answer (score 4):

How about $T=id$ and $F=-id$?